# Does this qualify as a covariate in a RMANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, ancova

I am confused as to whether a variable qualifies as a covariate in an RMANOVA. How can I find out and how do I use it?
In a (hypothetical) within-subject, counterbalanced order, I present 2 memory tasks - one is a simple word learning in a quiet setting, and the other has a more game like environment. I wish to see if memory for items learnt during the game was better that simple list learning. That makes for a simple RM-ANOVA with the two memory scores as within-subject variables, and order as a between subject variable. Right? But I also believe this effect will depend on how well the person played the game in the second condition. Perhaps, people who play the game well do not show much difference from control condition, but those who don't play the game so well, show a greater advantage.

In conclusion, I have 2 memory scores, and a game-performance score which should correlate with the difference in the two memory scores. Just not sure how to use it.

What do I do to look for such effects?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely in a gray zone, at best.

> That makes for a simple RM-ANOVA with the two memory scores as
>   within-subject variables, and order as a between subject variable.
>   Right?

Your underlying design would probably be thought of more usually as a two-period, two-treatment cross-over design.  That would be the area to look for not only the basic statistical methodology, but also to see the various issues around that type of design.

With this design covariates would usually be thought of as either at the subject-level, at the period-level, or at the subject-by-period-level.  (This is my own terminology just to try to bridge the gap.)

Subject-level covariates would be variates that change across subjects that would be thought of as unchanging over the periods of the study --- or perhaps as independent of time.  Examples would include sex, age, intelligence, or similar demographic or baseline characteristics.

Period-level covariates would be variates that change over time that would be thought of as independent of subjects.  Examples could include environmental variables such as temperature or humidity.

Subject-by-period-level covariates would be variates that were subject-specific and period-specific.  In other words, they vary across both subjects and across time.  Examples could include blood pressure, alertness, or other physical or physiological measurements that vary over shorter time frames than the study periods.

In your case, game performance is something that varies across subjects and perhaps also varies across periods, so is probably a subject-by-period-level covariate.  But, you would like to treat it as something like a subject-level covariate, perhaps because you only have one such measurement per subject or perhaps because you see it as reflecting an underlying trait.

> What do I do to look for such effects?

Even in the more well-defined cases where measurements are unambiguously subject-level or subject-by-period-level, it is more technical than one might wish.  Kenward and Roger (2009) provide a discussion of the issues. 
At best, your case seems like it would raise many questions.

[Kenward, Michael G., and James H. Roger (2009) The use of baseline covariates in crossover studies.  *Biostatistics* **11** (1):1--17.](http://biostatistics.oxfordjournals.org/content/11/1/1.full)